# Bower package manager illegible in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bower

Why does my Bower Package Manager look illegible but Nuget package manager looks fine. How do I fix this?

Here they are side by side on the same project as two tabbed forms, the one on the right is Bower.

[image: Bower in VS2015]

Visual Studio info:

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Professional

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1) 14.1.20203.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2 4.1.41102.0

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013 5.2.40314.0

NuGet Package Manager 3.4.2

NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the RC1 build of the Web Tools. It looks bad in the dark theme. It will be fixed when Web Tools are released for ASP.NET Core RC2.

Comment: Beware of this update. It's very buggy and a lot of ppl are having troubles. 
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/638 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935